# Why is the graph of the function $y=x^{2.9}$ not tangible on the negative side

Tags: graphing-functions

Why is the graph of $y=x^{2.9}$ intangible on the negative side?

[image: Why is the graph intangible on the negative side]

Comment: How do you define $x^{2.9}$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If x<0, x^(2.9)=x^(29/10) which is the 10th root of x^29, But x<0 implies x^29<0 so the tenth root of that is not a real number.

Comment: Why do you think $-5^{-2.9}$ is defined (and a real number)?

Comment: Note $(-5)^{-2.9}$ is undefined (in the reals), but you irrelevantly  computed $-(5^{-2.9}) = -0.00939$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$, one can define  $x^r$ with $r\notin\mathbb{Z}$ in two ways.

1. Define, for all real number $r$ that is not an integer, $$x^r=e^{r\ln{x}}$$ where $e$ is the exponential base and $\ln$ the natural logarithm.

As the natural logarithm is not defined when $x\leq0$ this means that the function $x\mapsto x^r$ with $r\notin\mathbb{Z}$ is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^+_\star$ if $r<0$, or $\mathbb{R}^+$ if $r>0$ (because of limit of $\exp(t)$ when $t\rightarrow-\infty$).

2. However there is a way to accept the case $x<0$ : if $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $r=\dfrac{1}{q}$ and $q$ odd, one can define $x^{1/q}$ as the unique real number $y$ (and possibly negative) where $y^q=x$.
   This can be extended to $r=\dfrac{p}{q}$ if $p\wedge q=1$ and $q$ is odd (this is how Geogebra works, actually).

If $r=2.9=\dfrac{29}{10}$, the denominator is even so $x$ can't be negative

Comment: The logarithmic definition for power is not the only one in common use for rational non-integer values. Fractional powers of form $x^(p/q)$ with $q$ odd are defined for negative $x.$

Comment: Agreed (that's the second part of my answer)

Comment: [sorry, didn't read that. got thrown by your opening "By definition..." which leads one to believe there is *not* a different way to define it.]

Comment: True, I update my answer to remove this misunderstanding